# first initialization component in android app

Tags: android

An android app can have multiple processes. I want to know which component will be the first one to start before other components start in each process so that I can do some initialization there. I am also fine with adding a component such as a service or contentprovider/broadcast receiver in the manifest file and mark it so that it starts first in each of the process of the android app.

Comment: What does 'start' mean? Loaded to the memory , or inited?

Comment: The component for which some method callback like onCreate or something else happens first?